# JavaScript Remove Multiple Values from Array Using Filter and Loop

Tags: javascript

I'm new here and need some help with writing a function `destroyer()` to remove multiple values from an array.

The destroyer() function passes in an array and additional numbers as arguments. The idea is to remove the numbers from the array.

E.g.

```
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3)
```

Output: `[1, 1]`

```
destroyer(["tree", "hamburger", 53], "tree", 53)
```

Output: `["hamburger"]`

```
destroyer([2, 3, 2, 3], 2, 3)
```

Output: `[]`

Note: the examples only show 2 additional numbers to remove. But the function destroyer() should be able to remove any number of values (i.e. 4, 5, or 6 parameters).

However, my code does not produce the same result. Specifically, using console.log, I see that my filterer function does not loop properly.

1) Can anyone help me debug?

2) Any better way to write this function?

Thank you very much!!!

```
function destroyer() {

  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); 

  var itemToRemove = args.slice(1);
  console.log(itemToRemove);
  var newArr = args[0];
  console.log(newArr);

  function filterer(value) { 

    for (var i = 0; i < itemToRemove.length; i++) {
      console.log(i);
      console.log(itemToRemove[i]);
      if (value != itemToRemove[i]) {
        return value;
      }
    } 
   }

  return newArr.filter(filterer);
}
```

Comment: If you told us what the criteria was for removing, instead of posting cryptic examples, it would probably be easier to help ?

Comment: In the first argument he passes an array, in the further the values he wants to remove

Comment: Do you always pass two values for removing? or it can be more? like `destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2,4, 3)`?

Comment: It can be any number of values, e.g. 3 values to remove in your example.

Comment: I smell freeCodeCamp ;D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `filterer` function can be much simpler:

```
function filterer (value) {
    return itemToRemove.indexOf(value) === -1;
}
```

Comment: @Neong, note, it can be not fast on big array, with many items to remove

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.prototype.indexOf()` can be inefficient compared to object property lookup in terms of time complexity. I would recommend looping through the additional arguments once and constructing an object with target elements to be destroyed as keys. Then you can check if a given value is a target or not within a filtering callback that you pass to `Array.prototype.filter()`.

```
function destroyer() {
    var arr = arguments.length && arguments[0] || [];
    var targets = {};
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        targets[arguments[i]] = true;
    }
    return arr.filter(function (x) {
        return targets[x] === undefined;
    });
}
```

One downside to this approach is that not all values in JS can be valid properties of an object, since properties must be strings. In this case, you're just using numbers as keys, and those numbers are implicitly converted to strings.

Comment: i think in this case better `targets[arguments[i]] = true` or something like and in filter function `targets[x] === undefiend`. because `hasOwnProperty` is more complex function and slowest with comparing to _undefined_

Comment: @Grundy Noted, I have edited the answer. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you Shashank and @Grundy for your help. It took me a while to understand this approach ;) Thank you for the perspective!

Answer (score 0):

We can pass the arguments an extra parameter to our callback function in our filter() method.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  return arr.filter(filterer(arguments)); // Pass arguments
}

function filterer(args) {
  return function(value) { // Actual filter function
    for (var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
      if (value === args[i]) // Seek
        return false; // Destroy
    }
    return true; // Otherwise keep
  };
}
```

This passes all 5 test cases for *freeCodeCamp | Basic Algorithm Scripting | Seek and Destroy*.

Answer (score -1):

A simple function

```
function filter(arr, arg1, arg2){

    var j = arr.length;
    while(j){

       if (arr.indexOf(arg1) > -1 || arr.indexOf(arg2) > -1){
          arr.splice(j - 1, 1);
       }
       j--
    }
}
```

Comment: what if should be three additional params? or four? :-)

Comment: In his requirement needs two arguments, I wrote this function for that

Comment: it just a sample, i think. also why you do two `indexOf` on every loop iteration, instead just testing array element and do splice if it equal arg1 or arg2?

Comment: I added another answer below

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear but it can be any number of values to be removed -- 2, 3, 4, 5 etc.

Comment: Please check my other answer below

Answer (score -1):

For multiple arguments

A simple function

```
function filter(){
    var j = -1; 
    for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
        j = arguments[0].indexOf(arguments[i]);
        if(j > -1){
           arguments[0].splice(j, 1);
        }
    }
    return arguments[0];
}
```

you can call this function with no of args
eg:

```
 filter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 1, 3, 5); //return [2,4,6,7,8,9]
 filter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 1); //return [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: you not need in `...,arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4` and `function filter(arr)` is enough

Comment: Yes, #Grundy but this function should call with an array and arguments

Comment: but now it seems like max args count is 4

Comment: It not depend on no of args

Comment: i not say that it depends:-) i say - it _seems like_

Comment: Ok then I edit it, user should call same as : filter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 1, 3, 5);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93042/discussion-between-grundy-and-azzi).

Comment: check this sample from OP: `destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3)` expects `[1,1]` but your code return `[1, 1, 2, 3]`

Comment: nope :-) `TypeError: arr[0].indexOf is not a function`

Comment: I deleted the ambiguity of the parameters now its works fine.

Comment: yep. you `return arr` but remove this definition

Answer (score -1):

There are really good answers here, but you can do it very clean in this way, remember you have an objects option in filter method which you can use in the callback function, in this case i'm using it like : *arguments[i]* so I can check every value in the arguments array

```
function destroyer(arr) {

   for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
     arr = arr.filter(isIn, arguments[i]);
   } 

   function isIn(element,index, array){
      if (element != this){
         return element;
      }
   }  
   return arr;
}
```