# JavaScript filter callback that uses arguments

Tags: javascript

The goal is to filter an array and remove all occurrences of elements specified in its argument list.

For example, given removeElements([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3,4], 2, 3), my output should be [1,1,4].

```
function removeElements(arr) {
//I got an error that says **functions** not allowed **inside loop**
  for(var i=1;i<arguments.length;i++){
    arr= arr.filter(function(e){
        return e!==arguments[i];
    });
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Second thing I tried is moving the filter out of the for loop.

```
function removeElements(arr) {
  function isNotEqual(e){
    return e!==this;
  }
  for(var i=1;i<arguments.length;i++){
    arr= arr.filter(isNotEqual,arguments[i]);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

None of them work. It always return arr as [1,2,3,1,2,3,4].
Can you please tell as to what is wrong in my usage? Or what is the approach for using filter in this scenario?

Comment: In the first snippet, the `arguments` variable will hold a different value for each `function`, including those that are embedded within other functions, like the iterator given to `.filter()`.

Comment: I don't know why you'd get an error message about calling a function inside a loop, but the first version won't work because in the inner function you reference `arguments` as if you are getting the outer function's arguments.

Comment: That "error message" is not a native JavaScript error. You must be using some kind of linter. Which one is it?

Comment: @FelixKling This is from freebootcamp.com

Comment: As @azzi suggests, this is the duplicate of the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274362/javascript-remove-multiple-values-from-array-using-filter-and-loop?lq=1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To try to explain the reasons the snippets didn't succeed:

1. Every function defines its own `arguments`, even when the function is embedded.

   ```
   function removeElements(arr) {
       console.log(arguments);
       // Arguments {
       //   0: Array [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       //   1: 2,
       //   2: 3
       // }

       arr = arr.filter(function (e) {
           console.log(arguments);
           // Arguments {
           //   0: 1, 2, 3, 1, ...             (each value in `arr`)
           //   1: 0, 1, 2, 3, ...             (each index)
           //   2: Array [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4] (`arr` itself)
           // }

           // ...
       });

       return arr;
   }

   removeElements([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4], 2, 3);
   ```

   By retrieving values from `arguments` inside of the iterator (`function(e) {...}`), the statement will compare `e` against values in the 2nd Arguments.

   ```
   for(var i=1;i<arguments.length;i++){
       arr = arr.filter(function(e){
           // 1st = 0              (the first index from `arr`)
           // 2nd = [1, 2, 3, ...] (the `arr` itself)
           console.log(arguments[i]);

           return e!==arguments[i];
       });
   }
   ```

   One option to resolve this is to access `arguments` outside of the iterator function, stashing the value in a variable that won't have the same conflict:

   ```
   for(var i=1;i<arguments.length;i++){
       var skip = arguments[i];
       arr = arr.filter(function (e) {
           return e !== skip;
       });
   }
   ```

   http://jsfiddle.net/y7evq6nq/
2. If you're not using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), the value of `this` will always be an Object.

   When you provide a primitive value for a `thisArg`, it will be boxed into its equivalent Object type. In this case, a `new Number`.

   ```
   function foo() {
       console.log(typeof this, this); // 'object' Number(3)
       return true;
   }

   [0].filter(foo, 3);
   ```

   And, since `===` first checks for type equality, a primitive and boxed number cannot be equal:

   ```
   var number = 3;
   var boxedNumber = new Number(3);

   console.log(typeof number);      // 'number'
   console.log(typeof boxedNumber); // 'object'

   console.log(typeof number === typeof boxedNumber); // false
   console.log(number === boxedNumber);               // false
   ```

   You can use the `.valueOf()` method to retrieve the primitive value from the object.

   ```
   function isNotEqual(e){
     return e!==this.valueOf();
   }
   ```

   http://jsfiddle.net/ow9b78bf/

   Or, you can try using strict mode, which allows `this` to hold a primitive value without boxing it.

Comment: Is it possible to pass more than one argument as thisArg?
`arr.filter(callback,thisArg1,thisArg2,thisArg3)`?

Comment: Not in that manner. `.filter()` only accepts one value for it and will use it for each call to the iterator. What you can do is pass an Array or other Object as the one value that in turns contains all of the other values you want to pass together.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Array.prototype.slice` to get the blacklisted elements in array form.

Then use `Array.prototype.indexOf` to see if a given element is in the array for the filter function.

http://jsfiddle.net/Loothof7/

```
function removeElements(arr) {
  var blacklist = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return arr.filter(function(e) {
    return blacklist.indexOf(e) == -1;
  });
}

alert(removeElements([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3,4], 2, 3));
```

Note that `Function.prototype.call` is used on `Array.prototype.slice` with the `this` scope argument of `arguments` instead of directly calling `arguments.slice` since `arguments` isn't actually a "real" array.

Answer (score 2):

`arguments` are function specific pseudo-variable. Using it inside callback will give arguments of callback and not outer function.

```
function removeElements(arr) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  for(var i=1;i<args.length;i++){
    arr= arr.filter(function(e){
        return e!==args[i];
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have already answered this type of question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274362/javascript-remove-multiple-values-from-array-using-filter-and-loop/33275091#33275091) any way I post it to you

A simple function

```
function filter(){
    var j = -1; 
    for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
        j = arguments[0].indexOf(arguments[i]);
        if(j > -1){
           arguments[0].splice(j, 1);
        }
    }
    return arguments[0];
}
```

you can call this function with no of args eg:

```
 filter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 1, 3, 5); //return [2,4,6,7,8,9]
 filter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 1); //return [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will use a callback function to check against the two numbers given in the arguments list.

```js
function removeElements(arr, num1, num2){
  return arr.filter(numChecks(num1, num2));
  
}
function numChecks(num1, num2){
  return function(element){
    return element !== num1 && element !== num2;
  }
}
removeElements([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3,4], 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do, maybe I'm wrong.

```
var result = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4].filter(function(item) {
  return item !== 1 && item !== 2;
});

console.log(result); // [3, 3, 4]
```

**UPDATE:**

This function can do the job you want passing the items to be remove as an array instead of turning the `arguments[1]` param an **Array** using `slice.call()`:

```
function removeItems(arr, items) {
  return arr.filter(function (elem) {
    return items.indexOf(elem) === -1;
  });
}

var result = removeItems([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3]);

console.log(result); // [1, 1, 4]
```

Comment: No, I used `1` and `2` instead of `2` and `3`, you just have to change the values, or pass them as arguments to a function, but that's the way filter works

Comment: but 1 and 2 needs to be pass as argument you have hardcoded

Answer (score -1):

There are really good answers here, but you can do it very clean in this way, remember you have an objects option in filter method which you can use in the callback function, in this case i'm using it like : arguments[i] so I can check every value in the arguments array

```
function destroyer(arr) {

   for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
     arr = arr.filter(isIn, arguments[i]);
   } 

  function isIn(element,index, array){
     if (element != this){
        return element;
     }
  }  

  return arr;
}
```

Comment: explain your answer - where did "index" and "array" come from? where did you access the arguments inside the filter function?